# Adding slanted text to UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to add some text in a diagonal angle similar to the [image](http://slideshow.rubyforge.org/slidy/slidy/w3c-logo-slanted.jpg) (the image shows that the text is slanted).

How can i add a slanted text to a `UILabel` programatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `CGAffineTransform`.
As using this will rotate your label, so you can do like below

in your .h file

```
UILabel *myLabel;
```

in your .m file
if you want to show the slanted text at starting then write below code in `viewDidLoad` function

```
myLabel.text=@"Hello world";
CGAffineTransform transformRotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI  * -90 / 180.0));
//above you can change the angle so that you can get the required rotation
myLabel.transform = transformRotate;
```

Comment: but, where do i add the text or the String "Example". I need "Example" to rotate, How do i edit the above code to do that?